# $|a-b| \leq C_1 $ implies $|a|^m-|b|^m \leq C_2 $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I want to show that

> For $a(t),b(t) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^3$, $|a(t)-b(t)| \leq C_1 $ implies $|a(t)|^m-|b(t)|^m \leq C_2 $, where $C_i$ are some constants and $m$ is any integer.

This means that if $|a-b|$ is unifomly bounded, then $|a|^m-|b|^m$ is also unifomly bounded.

I tried to prove it using induction, but it failed.

How to prove it?

Comment: Does $C_2$ depend on $m$?

Comment: @ElliotG Probably not.